C# .NET code is failing to build because it's looking for a folder that does not exist
My solution fails to build throwing two errors saying "The local source 'path/repo/foldername' doesn't exist." The folder used to exist, but has long since been deleted. I cannot find any code anywhere on my computer referencing foldername.
I have searched the two proj files indicated in the error and there is no string matching "foldername".
I have searched the entire solution (ctrl + shift + f) and I have searched my entire computer (grep), with 0 matches found, so I cannot find any code anywhere that is trying to access that folder.
I have re-cloned the repo multiple times, restarted VS/my computer multiple times, and reinstalled VS.
When I re-clone the repo, I rename 'repo' to 'old-repo', clone 'new-repo', build 'new-repo' and the path in the error stays as 'path/repo/foldername,' instead of either 'path/old-repo/foldername' or 'path/new-repo/foldername'
The code runs just fine locally. When I pushed up the repo, other people can clone it and run/build just fine. My pipeline builds the code just fine. This is only happening for me locally.
Please help me figure out what is going on and how to fix it.

What happens if you CREATE that folder (as a test)? Does the error go away?

I googled your error and it points to NuGet. Click Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Settings -> Package Sources on the left. Probably just delete the non-existent source. If you don't have a package source with the nuget packages referenced in your project then you won't be able to build.

@Evelyn - that was the solution. Thanks so much!!

Clearing the Visual Studio cache can often resolve these kinds of issues.
Navigate to the following directory and delete the entire ComponentModelCache folder. This will force Visual Studio to recreate it the next time it starts, which can resolve issues related to cached data.
%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\<version>\ComponentModelCache

Also clear the Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF) cache can also help.
%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\<version>\MEFCache

Then clean the .vs Folder. In the root directory of your solution, there is a hidden .vs folder. Delete this folder to clear any cached settings specific to your solution.
